# How to find a word in a string, which is used multiple times without a quote

Tags: regex, vb.net

I need to find a solution for the following problem:
I know a word, which should be found in a string.
Let's say: "DailyReport" is the word, I am looking for
The string to search looks like this:
"DailyReportDailyReportDetails DailyReport"

Now, what I try to achieve is, that the first match of "DailyReport" must be deleted, but the other two not.
So, the resulting string should be: "DailyReportDetails DailyReport"

All I found so far, when matching words with RegEx is, when the words are seperated by an empty string. But this is not, what I am looking for.

THX for any tip in the right direction

Comment: search for lookahead and back-references, that will help you to solve your problem

Comment: Hey
Tried to use the following code RegEx, but still brings all parts:

(?<Test>DailyReport)(?!s)(?<=\1)

Comment: try this `(?<Test>DailyReport)(?=\1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx for all of your help
I did something similar like the suggestion of user11982798
I split the name by regex and use the index and length of the matches:

```
Dim locReturnString = "DailyReportDailyReportDetails DailyReport"     
Dim locValueToReplaye = "DailyReport"
Dim locDoubleCheckValuesToReplace = Regex.Matches(locReturnString, String.Format("((?<TestName>{0}))", locValueToReplace))
Dim locNewIndexAfterReplacing As Integer = 0
If locDoubleCheckValuesToReplace.Count > 1 Then
   For locDoubleCheckValueToReplace = 0 To locDoubleCheckValuesToReplace.Count - 1 Step 1
       If locDoubleCheckValueToReplace + 1 > locDoubleCheckValuesToReplace.Count - 1 Then
          Exit For
       End If
       Dim locValueToCheck = locDoubleCheckValuesToReplace(locDoubleCheckValueToReplace)
       If locValueToCheck.Index + locValueToCheck.Length = locDoubleCheckValuesToReplace(locDoubleCheckValueToReplace + 1).Index Then
          locReturnString = String.Format("{0}{1}", locReturnString.Substring(0, locValueToCheck.Index - locNewIndexAfterReplacing),
                                                    locReturnString.Substring(locValueToCheck.Index + locValueToCheck.Length - locNewIndexAfterReplacing))
          locNewIndexAfterReplacing = locValueToCheck.Length
        End If
   Next
End If
```

THX a lot

Answer (score 0):

Without regex, may be you can test this:

```
    str = "DailyReportDailyReportDetails DailyReport"
    strArr = str.Split(New String() {"DailyReport"}, StringSplitOptions.None)

    Dim mycnt As Integer = 0
    Dim myArrList As New List(Of String)
    For count = 0 To strArr.Length - 1
        If strArr(count) = "" Then
            If mycnt = 0 Then myArrList.Add(strArr(count))
            mycnt += 1
        Else
            myArrList.Add(strArr(count))
            mycnt = 0
        End If
    Next
    Dim mystr As String = String.Join("DailyReport", myArrList.ToArray)
```

But if your string :
"DailyReportDailyReportDetails DailyReport DailyReportDailyReportDailyReport",

so you will have your myStr 
"DailyReporDetails DailyReport DailyReport"

Comment: THX for this type of solution @user11982798
I did something similar, what works really fine.